# How to display a temp table where values are inserted dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

Basically I have this TSQL which looks up a condition in all tables in a database and trying to insert the records into this temp table. I'm having difficulty to display this temp table #TEMP1 at the end of execution.

```
OPEN MyCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Table
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 
        set @SQL = N'IF EXISTS(select 1 from Prod.' + @Table + ' where usedDate IS NULL)' + 
 'select ''' + @Table + ''' as TableName,* INTO #TEMP1 from Prod.' + @Table + ' WHERE usedDate IS NULL '

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Table
END;
CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
```

Comment: Since  #temp is created inside dynamic SQL, it can be accessed within that scope only

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **#TEMP1** in

```
'select ''' + @Table + ''' as TableName,* INTO #TEMP1 from Prod.' + @Table + ' WHERE usedDate IS NULL '
```

You can use global temp **##TEMP1** table as

```
'select ''' + @Table + ''' as TableName,* INTO ##TEMP1 from Prod.' + @Table + ' WHERE usedDate IS NULL '
```

But note that, if cursor iterates, this will fail as you cannot insert into a table more than once.

To address that issue

concatenate the value of **@Table** to ##TEMP1

or before the next iteration, drop the table ##TEMP1